# Delaunay Triangulation simplices - scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, delaunay, scipy-spatial

I was reading about [Delaunay (scipy)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) and came across the code:

```
import numpy as np
points = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1.1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])

from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
tri = Delaunay(points)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.triplot(points[:,0], points[:,1], tri.simplices.copy())
plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'o')
plt.show()
```

As far as I understand, a simplex is the generalization of a triangle to higher dimensions.

I don't understand the meaning of the code below and would like help understanding it:

```
# Point indices and coordinates for the two triangles forming the triangulation:

tri.simplices
array([[3, 2, 0],
       [3, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)

points[tri.simplices]
array([[[ 1. ,  1. ],
        [ 1. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ]],
       [[ 1. ,  1. ],
        [ 0. ,  1.1],
        [ 0. ,  0. ]]])

Triangle 0 is the only neighbor of triangle 1, and it’s opposite to vertex 1 of triangle 1:


tri.neighbors[1]
# array([-1,  0, -1], dtype=int32)

points[tri.simplices[1,1]]
array([ 0. ,  1.1])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This code is creating a Delaunay triangulation from four vertices containing two triangles. The triangulation looks like this:

[image: triangulation]

The code begins by defining the four vertices in an array:

```
points = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1.1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
```

Next, scipy constructs a Delaunay triangulation for these points:

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
tri = Delaunay(points)
```

Now, tri.simplices contains a list of triangles (in this 2D case) in the Delaunay triangulation. Each triangle is represented as three integers: each value represents a index in to the original points array.

```
tri.simplices
array([[3, 2, 0],
       [3, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

So [3,2,0] is the triangle between vertex 3 (1,1), vertex  2 (1,0) and vertex 0 (0,0). The next code connects the points and tri data structures to compute the coordinates of the vertices of each triangle, eliminating the indirection:

```
points[tri.simplices]
array([[[ 1. ,  1. ],
        [ 1. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ]],
       [[ 1. ,  1. ],
        [ 0. ,  1.1],
        [ 0. ,  0. ]]])
```

The tri.neighbors array contains information about which triangles are adjacent to each other.

```
tri.neighbors[1]
# array([-1,  0, -1], dtype=int32)
```

Recall that triangle 1 (tri.simplices in position 1) has vertices [3,1,0]. Triangle 0 is neighboring Triangle 1 opposite vertex 1, which is why the result has value 0 in the second element (corresponding to 1 in [3,1,0]). There are no triangles opposite vertex 3 (i.e., connected along the edge between vertex 0 and 1) or opposite vertex 0, so the neighbors array contains -1 in those positions.

Finally, is this code.

```
points[tri.simplices[1,1]]
array([ 0. ,  1.1])
```

Recalling the tri.simplices data structure above, there is a value 1 contained in position 1 in simplex 1 (i.e., [3,1,0]. This line is just looking up the coordinates of vertex 1.

As a final note, the order of vertices in the simplices returned is not required to match this original example and can vary from version to version. Here is a recent run matching an observation in the comment below which is inconsistent with the original vertex order (provided in the original documentation):

[image]

Comment: The output of `tri.neighbors[0]` is `array([ 1, -1, -1], dtype=int32)`. But according to the figure/plot, shouldn't the output instead be `array([-1, 1, -1], dtype=int32)` because triangle 1 is neighboring triangle 0 and opposite to vertex 2 (of triangle 0) is vertex 1 (of triangle 1)? I don't get how is vertex 1 opposite to vertex 3 according to output?

Comment: When I actually run this code, I happen to get the vertices of the triangle in position 0 to be listed in a different order. I will update the answer with some details.